# Displaying new records ascending in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my table when I use addRow() method I receive data in this order:

1. 
2. 
3. 

I want to receive this order

3.
2.
1.

This is my method addRow()

```
function addRow(data){ 
                var row = '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.id +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.date_fault +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.institution +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.product_name +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.description_fault +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.serviceman +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.department +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.contact_details +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ data.created_at +'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+ '<label class="btn btn-danger" for="">Oczekuje</label>' +'</td>'+
                        '<td><button class="btn btn-success btn-show"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>'+
                        '<button class="btn btn-primary mt-1 btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>'+
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger mt-1 btn-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                $('thead').append(row);
            }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: This method just deals with it after you've gotten the data.  You need to look at who is sending the data and deal with the order there.

Comment: Or use `prepend` instead of `append`.http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ but it would be better to deal with something that specific when before you send the data.  Otherwise you are then stuck with always prepending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `prepend` instead of `append`. `prepend` attaches the child at the top of the parent, so the final order would be as desired:

3

2

1

Here's some info on it: [Prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: Jaime thank you! This is work :) That's right I could look into the documentation from append I would get this information about prepend. Regards!